# check the compatibility of the binary

Tags: c++, linux, compatibility

I have a shared folder on multiple machines. The machines are all linux but not exactly the same, so that the binary compiled on machine A may or may not run successfully on machine B. When it does not work, the binary will not immediately fail, but it will run for some time until it throw some "Illegal Instructions" error.

Therefore I was wondering, is there a good way to check the compatibility of the binary on the machine before I really runs it? All programs are written in C++ and I have access to the source code.

Comment: If you have access to the source code, why not compile multiple versions and use symlinks to point to the right one by machine?

Comment: We use CMake and VS2013 on Windows. Depending on platform (32 bit, 64 bit) and mode (debug, release, etc.), the intermediate files and binaries are stored in a respective directory so that they get never mixed. (i.e. build settings are used to name appropriate output directories.) I would try something similar in your case and combine this with the suggest of Henno Bransma. (I'm quite sure you can google for a tutorial how to do this with `make` or `cmake` on Linux.) Sorry, that I don't provide more details - thanks to cmake and VS I had never to care about...

Comment: Have you investigated **why** it results in illegal instruction? It might be an actual flaw in your program that manifests itself only on certain machines. If it is that the code actually contains instructions that are only valid on some machines it sounds like you've set the compiler to compile for processor X with which processor Y is not compatible with (if that's the case, compile for processor Z instead which X and Y are both compatible with).